# what is d.source? [Documentation is referring itself]

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I wonder what does d.source and what the source it is referring.

In the d3 api documentation explains if source is specified...

> link.source([source])Source If source is specified, sets the source
>   accessor to the specified function and returns this link generator. If
>   source is not specified, returns the current source accessor, which
>   defaults to:
>
> function source(d) {   return d.source; }

doesn't even tell me what 'source' is.
The code that I encountered 'source' is as below.

```
function showLinkArrayElements(data, title) {
  d3.select('#content')
    .append('div')
    .html('<span>' + title + '</span>: ' + data.map(function(d) {return d.source.data.name + ' -> ' + d.target.data.name;}).join(', '))
}
```

Can anyone give me a general walk-through about source and d.source/d.target that this code is talking about?

Thank you

Entire code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Hierarchy examples</title>
</head>

<style>
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

div {
  margin: 20px;
}

div span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

<body>
  <div id="content"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var data = {
  "name": "A1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "C1",
          "value": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "C2",
          "value": 300
        },
        {
          "name": "C3",
          "value": 200
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "B2",
      "value": 200
    }
  ]
};

function showArrayElements(data, title) {
  d3.select('#content')
    .append('div')
    .html('<span>' + title + '</span>: ' + data.map(function(d) {return d.data.name;}).join(', '))
}

function showLinkArrayElements(data, title) {
  d3.select('#content')
    .append('div')
    .html('<span>' + title + '</span>: ' + data.map(function(d) {return d.source.data.name + ' -> ' + d.target.data.name;}).join(', '))
}

var root = d3.hierarchy(data)

var ancestors = root.children[0].children[1].ancestors()
var descendants = root.descendants()
var leaves = root.leaves()
var path = root.path(root.children[0].children[1])
var links = root.links()

showArrayElements(ancestors, "root.children[0].children[1].ancestors()")
showArrayElements(descendants, "root.descendants()")
showArrayElements(leaves, "root.leaves()")
showArrayElements(path, "root.path(root.children[0].children[1])")
showLinkArrayElements(links, "root.links()")



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each item in the links array (returned by `root.links()`) created by the hierarchical layout has a source and target property, these are the nodes that are connected by the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d.source is linked to the data variable as you are mapping the data (so the source is basically a property of a d3 link object).
Check the reference for the [array mapping method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

node.links() -> Returns an array of links for this node, where each link is an object that defines source and target properties. The source of each link is the parent node, and the target is a child node.

Comment: Hi, I understood mapping? but I think I have zero knowledge about what source is and what target is which make me have a hardtime to understand the code. Can you explain what source & target is? Thank you. I read through the documentation but can't understand.

Comment: check this out @BS100 https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/v1.1.9/README.md#node_links